# morphing animation in vertex shader

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-2.0, morphing

To interpolate vertex position in vertex shader for morphing animation between two morph target's I send to shader two vertex positions.  At now i have a mesh which has about 600 morph target's and I have a feeling that it is not a good idea trying to send to vertex shader 600 vertex positions. Could someone please tell me what is the correct way to animate object with so much morph targets?

P.S. I'm very new to 3d programming.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is simple: only send the morph target data you actually intend to use.

Put all of your morph target data in a single buffer. When it comes time to render, use `glVertexAttribPointer` on each of the two position attributes you are morphing between. Use that function to specify the byte offset for that particular morph target.

As an example, imagine the following buffer memory layout:

```
|----Morph Target 0----|----Morph Target 1----|----...----|----Morph Target N----|
K                      L                      M           Z
```

To blend between targets 0 and 1, you call `glVertexAttribPointer(0, ..., (void*)K)` and `glVertexAttribPointer(1, ..., (void*)L)`, where `K` and `L` are the offsets of the morph targets in the buffer.

Obviously, you can only blend between two morph targets. But you can blend between any two.

> I have a feeling that it is not a good idea trying to send to vertex shader 600 vertex positions.

It's more that it's not possible. The number of attributes is limited by the implementation, and that number is usually small (between 16 and 32).